# How to merge two UITextView in iPhone?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, scroll, uitextview

I am worked in autocomplete text in textview, so I am using two `UITextView` the first `UITextView` (`duplicateTextView`) is background text like watermark text and the second `UITextView` (`customTextView`) is user entering the text. When the user enters multiline text in textview, the `customTextView` scrolls automatically but the `duplicateTextView` is not scrolling. So, how can I scroll the `duplicateTextView` while the multiline text is enters? Is it possible to merge two `UITextView` together in iPhone?

Here I tried the source code:

```
duplicateTextView = [[UITextView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 50, 320, 100)];
duplicateTextView.delegate = self;
duplicateTextView.scrollEnabled = YES;
duplicateTextView.font = [UIFont fontWithName:@"Helvetica" size:14];
duplicateTextView.textColor = [UIColor lightGrayColor];
[self.view addSubview:duplicateTextView];

customTextView = [[UITextView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 320, 100)];
customTextView.layer.borderWidth = 2.0;
customTextView.delegate = self;
customTextView.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
customTextView.layer.borderColor = [UIColor blackColor].CGColor;
customTextView.font = [UIFont fontWithName:@"Helvetica" size:14];
customTextView.textColor = [UIColor blackColor];
[duplicateTextView addSubview:customTextView];
```

Comment: USing the aboove code you cant interact with duplicateTextView because you added customTextView to it

Comment: this is not customTextView, just UITextView

Comment: please any one reply me.

Answer (score 0):

As @KAREEM MAHAMMED tried to explain, you're adding customTextView to your duplicateTextView in the last line of code you posted. Perhaps you meant to do the following instead:
`[self.view addSubview:customTextView];`

Perhaps I misunderstood your question. I'm adding some code here so you can see a working example:

.h file:

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

@class TestViewController;

@interface TestAppDelegate : 
NSObject <UIApplicationDelegate, UIScrollViewDelegate, UITextViewDelegate> 
{
    UIWindow *window;
    TestViewController *viewController;

    UITextView *customTextView;
    UITextView *duplicateTextView;
}

@property (nonatomic, retain) IBOutlet UIWindow *window;
@property (nonatomic, retain) IBOutlet TestViewController *viewController;

-(void)syncScroll;

@end
```

and the .m file:

```
#import "TestAppDelegate.h"
#import "TestViewController.h"

@implementation TestAppDelegate

@synthesize window;
@synthesize viewController;


#pragma mark -
#pragma mark Application lifecycle

- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions {    

    // custom
    customTextView = [[[UITextView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(10.0, 10.0, 80.0, 125.0)] autorelease];
    customTextView.backgroundColor = [UIColor whiteColor];
    [viewController.view addSubview:customTextView];

    // duplicate
    duplicateTextView = [[[UITextView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(170.0, 10.0, 80.0, 125.0)] autorelease];
    duplicateTextView.backgroundColor = [UIColor whiteColor];
    duplicateTextView.editable = NO;
    duplicateTextView.scrollEnabled = NO;
    [viewController.view addSubview:duplicateTextView];

    // whenever text is entered into the customTextView then sync scrolling
    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self
                                             selector:@selector(syncScroll)
                                                 name:UITextViewTextDidChangeNotification 
                                               object:customTextView];
    customTextView.delegate = self;

    // Add the view controller's view to the window and display.
    [self.window addSubview:viewController.view];
    [self.window makeKeyAndVisible];

    // have keyboard show up in customTextView
    [customTextView becomeFirstResponder];

    return YES;
}

#pragma mark -
#pragma mark Memory management

- (void)dealloc {
    [viewController release];
    [window release];
    [super dealloc];
}

#pragma mark -
#pragma mark Other Methods

- (void)scrollViewDidScroll:(UIScrollView *)scrollView {
    [self syncScroll];
}

-(void)syncScroll {
    duplicateTextView.text = customTextView.text;
    [duplicateTextView setContentOffset:customTextView.contentOffset];  
}


@end
```

Comment: Mr.ragamufin i have tired your suggestion. But, still the customTextView scrolls above and the duplicateTextView stay there. Thanks.

Comment: First of all both textviews are not in the same position. duplicate is at 0,0 and custom at 0,0. Secondly, as the user types into the custom one you should be placing the same text into the duplicate one, I don't think it gets there automatically. The user, I think, can only type into one box at a time. Try adding code to paste whatever the user is typing in custom into the duplicate. Make sense?

Comment: I've added some code to my answer to clarify, please take a second look.

Comment: Mr.ragamufin. Thanks for your answer. I hope it will work for Mr.Sampath kumar. Thanks.

Comment: Mr.Ragamufin. Your code is working charm. I think it is helping lot to Mr.Sampath. Thanks.

Comment: I don't know... @Sampath must be busy